# ¿Por qué me da este error? (Asynctask con notificaciones Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas. Tengo un ejercicio de crear notificaciones. En él me dice que cree la notificación dentro del método onPreExecute(), pero me da un error al escribir getSystemService(). Android Studio me dice que no es capaz de encontrar ese método. Este es el código:

```
public class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   Notification miNotificacion;
   NotificationManager miNotificacionManager;


   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       miNotificacionManager = (NotificationManager) 
       getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values){

   }
}
```

Comment: El método `getSystemService()` no existe dentro del esquema AsyncTask. Te recomiendo que si desde aquí necesitas levantar una notificación uses un callback que se ejecute en tu actividad. Ahora solo para que pruebes, pasa por parametros la actividad y has actividad.getSystemService()... el compilador debe de permitirlo pero no es una buena práctica.

Comment: @PacoPepe bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio. Con respecto a tu pregunta, me gustaría ver cual es el ejercicio que te indica crear una notificación dentro de onPreExecute()?, en este caso para getSystemService() necesitas el contexto. Me parece que necesitaras ayuda en crear la notificación.

Comment: Genial. He conseguido acabarlo gracias a vuestra ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`getSystemService()` pertenece al `Context` no al `AsyncTask`. Intenta enviando el contexto como parametro al `AsyncTask`. Por ejemplo:

```
public class MiTarea extends AsyncTask { Notification miNotificacion; NotificationManager miNotificacionManager;

    private Context _context;
    public MiTarea(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        miNotificacionManager = (NotificationManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values){

    }
}
```

Entonces cuando necesites inicializar MiTarea, tendras que enviar el contexto:

```
public class MiActividad extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state)
    {

        // this representa el contexto
        new MiTarea(this).Execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque el -1? Quien lo hizo que se explique.

Answer (score -1):

En este caso estas necesitando el Contexto , debes agregar un constructor para recibir el Contexto y de esta forma poder llamar `getSystemService()` :

```
public class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

   private Context mContext;
   Notification miNotificacion;
   NotificationManager miNotificacionManager;

   //* Constructor.  
   public MiTarea(Context context) {
      mContext = context;
   } 


   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       miNotificacionManager = (NotificationManager) 

       //Teniendo el contexto ahora puedes llamar getSystemService();
       //getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values){

   }
}
```

Por lo tanto cuando llames el `Asynctask` debes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
MiTarea task = new MiTarea (getApplicationContext());
task.execute();
```

Comment: -1 ¿? es bueno agregar una explicación para corregir en caso de algún error.